# How to update a progress bar so it increases smoothly?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I'm using progress bar of WPF (C#) to describe the process's progress.

My algorithm is below:

```
DoSomethingCode1();
ProgressBar.SetPercent(10); // 10%
DoSomethingCode2();
ProgressBar.SetPercent(20); // 20%

...

DoSomethingCode10();
ProgressBar.SetPercent(100); // 100%
```

It's ok, but it will make the progress bar was not sequent.

Someone can tell me some suggestions that make the progress bar is updated softly?

Comment: Do not manipulate UIElements in code. Learn MVVM. Use a background thread to perform your operations and then dispatch the update of the percentage property to the UI Thread.

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774473/using-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-in-wpf) might help you out.

Comment: What does "not sequent" mean? What is "soft updating"?

Comment: @HighCore, Abzy: Thank you, but it is not my problem, The above code is Pseudocode.

Comment: @Patrick: I don't know which words can describe them exactly!
But from above code, you can see the progress bar will update to 10% -> 20% -> ... -> 100%, it look not smooth.

Comment: @Patrick - TTGroup wants  it to, instead of jumping directly to 100 from 10, to update by gliding to 100%.

Comment: Thank you, I have been waiting in this thread for more than 1.5 years wondering that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could call the `BeginAnimation` method to animate the `ProgressBar`'s `Value` property. In my example below, I used a `DoubleAnimation`.

I created an extension method that takes in the desired percentage:

```
public static class ProgressBarExtensions
{
    private static TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

    public static void SetPercent(this ProgressBar progressBar, double percentage)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(percentage, duration);
        progressBar.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, animation);          
    }
}
```

So in your code you could simply call:

```
myProgressBar.SetPercent(50);
```

Doing this simply smooths out the transition so it looks nicer. To quote another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396133/1399567): "The idea is that a progress bar reports *actual progress* - not time elapsed. It's not intended to be an animation that just indicates *something is happening*." However, the default style of the progress bar does have a pulsating effect which can imply work is happening.

Comment: @Matt  nice.  What are your references?  the things you put after "using"?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - After a little research - add presentationcore.dll to references, then "using System.Windows.Media".  See [This Microsoft Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What .NET version is this? There is no BeginAnimation event on the ProgressBar?

Answer (score 44):

You can use a behavior!

```
public class ProgressBarSmoother
{
    public static double GetSmoothValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(SmoothValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSmoothValue(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SmoothValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmoothValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SmoothValue", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBarSmoother), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, changing));

    private static void changing(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var anim = new DoubleAnimation((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue, new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,250));
        (d as ProgressBar).BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, anim, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
    }
}
```

Your XAML would look like this:

```
<ProgressBar local:ProgressBarSmoother.SmoothValue="{Binding Progress}">
```

Whenever the `Progress` property you are binding to in the xaml changes, the code in the ProgressBarSmoother behavior will run, adding the animation to the progress bar for you with the appropriate values for `To` and `From`!

Comment: I added this solution because it allows you to decouple whatever is reporting progress and the view that contains the progress bar.

Comment: Love this. Adjusted the duration a little bit, works like a charm. However, since the standard progress bar in Windows since Vista does this, it should have already been in the WPF progress bar...

Comment: was a perfect drop in solution for my little client. This rocks, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can modify the style of the progressbar and set an Easing function to it's storyboard that modifies the "filling" of the progressbar and by doing that it will have a smooth transition.

Answer (score -1):

try this out.

```
private void updateProgressBar(int percent)
    {
        if (ProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateProgressBarCallback cb = new updateProgressBarCallback(updateProgressBar);
            this.Invoke(cb, new object[] { percent });
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressBar.Value = percent;
            ProgressBar.Update();
            ProgressBar.Refresh();
            ProgressBar.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry not working for me. I copied and pasted your code snippet. The errors saying the following :  System.Windows.Control.ProgressBar does not contain definition for Update,Refresh,Invalidate. The namespace name updateProgressBarCallback could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: if you did this, you would need something like:    delegate void updateProgressBarCallback(int percent); added to the code.

Comment: If your UI thread is busy, these draw calls will go into the event queue and happen all at once. The progress bar won't animate.