# Binding smooth animation on ValueChanged event for a XAML ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

i searched a lot about this but can't find a solution for my exact case:

First, i'm doing a little download manager, i list all my downloads in a **listview** element.
My **Listview** (named `downloadListXaml`) have some **GridViewColumn** binded to a my element (stuff like file name, file size, and a progress bar).
Every download is managed by a *separate thread*, every thread just update the **progress** value binded to my **ProgressBar**.

In my initial project every thread refreshed the UI on every change to **Progress** but this make the entire UI freeze sometime.
So i maked a separate thread that refresh my **Listview** every 100ms and ONLY if some download thread are active, here the simple code used for refresh:

```
downloadListXaml.Items.Refresh();
```

This works and UI is always responsive, but the progress bar animation just jumps every 100ms to the next value, not good looking at all.

I want to smootly refresh it, and i found some solution, like this: [How to update a progress bar so it increases smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485818/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-so-it-increases-smoothly)

The problem in that solution is that i need to refeer to my **ProgressBar** xaml element, but i just can access to my *object binded* to the **ProgressBar**.

So, i think my only solution is solve this **XAML-Side**, attaching an animation to the `ValueChanged` event of the **ProgressBar**.

I'm really new to XAML and i'm not even sure i can do this. Is this possible? How can i do it?

**TL;DR version**: i don't know how to animate a **ProgressBar** value change working only in **XAML** when ProgressBar value is binded to a code-side managed object.

Comment: Are you using Dispatcher to update the UI?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485818/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-so-it-increases-smoothly

Comment: No don't need to call `Refresh()` in the UI element. Just update the progress property value and call NotifyPropertyChange().

Answer (score 0):

i used the ProgressBarSmoother implementation from this answer: [How to update a progress bar so it increases smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485818/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-so-it-increases-smoothly)

it works well, but in my case it tries to animate ProgressBar from **0** to **correct value**. So i had to add the "*last drawn value*" in my object binded to **ListView** and animate from that value to current progress value.

Maybe not the best solution but looks really smooth and UI is responsive! I like that :)