# Delay with WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a `ProgressBar` that can animate from 0 to some value. Everything works fine most of time ...

I'm using the code from [Owen Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485818/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-so-it-increases-smoothly). Have some changes like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SmoothValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SmoothValue", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBarSmoother), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0d,  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, changing, coerceValueCallback, false, System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));


private static object coerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ (double)baseValue } coercevalue");
    return baseValue;
}

public static void changing(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBarSmoother obj = d as ProgressBarSmoother;
    Console.WriteLine($"Contador: {++obj.Count}. Valor novo: { e.NewValue }");
    if ((double)e.NewValue == 0)
    {
        obj.ResetAnimation();

        Console.WriteLine($"Contador: {++obj.Count}");
        obj.Value = 0;
        return;
    }

    obj.Animation = new DoubleAnimation(0d, (double)e.NewValue, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double)e.NewValue));
    obj.Animation.Completed += (sender, arg) =>
    {
        obj.Animation = null;
        obj.Value = 0;
        obj.BeginAnimation(ValueProperty, null, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);

        Console.WriteLine("Animation completed");
    };

    obj.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    obj.BeginAnimation(ValueProperty, obj.Animation, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);

    Console.WriteLine($"Contador: {++obj.Count}");
}

// Basically the code that changes the progressbar value is this
private void Controller_OnPlayerChangedState(object sender, MultiPlayerController.OnChangeStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState == AudioPlayer_State.Playing)
    {
        Duration = AudioPanel.Controller.GetDuration();

        panel.SetCurrentPositionAsync (Duration);
    }
    else if(e.NewState != AudioPlayer_State.Playing && e.NewState != AudioPlayer_State.Paused)
    {
        panel.SetCurrentPositionAsync ((long)0);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

(have a lot of code just for test and see whats happining)

I've an Audio Player and the `progressbar` is to see the actual position of audio (cannot be paused, only stopped). The stop button works fine. The problem is when Repeat status it's activated.
I receive a event from my dll of Stopped (set value to 0 and my animation goes away) and a few moments later (less then 0ms most of time) a Playing, so I have to update the `progressbar` animation with the duration.

Sometimes my animation is not called and I put some logs to discover wht. When is not called, `CoerceValueCallback` happens just one time. And when works, called two times: one with 0, when I destroy the older animation and other with the new duration (same as before).

Just for test, I've put a `Thread.Sleep` inside the code which changes the value to new duration and works like a charm. My thinking is the delay to change the new value... Basically I need to set to 0 and after to new value.

Can I remove the check of older value needs to be different from newer? Or I can update instantly the value?

### Solution until this moment

I created a public function on my control `ProgressBarSmoother` called `ResetAnimation`

```
public void ResetAnimation()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        SmoothValue = 0;
    });
}
```

And created a `getter/setter` of `SmoothValue`

```
public double SmoothValue
{
    get => (double)GetValue(SmoothValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(SmoothValueProperty, value);
}
```

On my `SetCurrentPositionAsync`,

```
public void SetCurrentPositionAsync (long position)
{
    if (position == 0)
        progressBar.ResetAnimation();

    CurrentPositionAsync = position;
}
```

And my changing:

```
public static void changing(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBarSmoother obj = d as ProgressBarSmoother;
    if ((double)e.NewValue == 0)
    {
        obj.BeginAnimation(ValueProperty, null, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);

        return;
    }

    obj.Animation = new DoubleAnimation(0d, (double)e.NewValue, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double)e.NewValue));
    obj.BeginAnimation(ValueProperty, obj.Animation, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
}
```

So.. When I set 0, I instantly call `ResetAnimation` that can set the Value of property and set on field correctly instead of calling `OnPropertyChanged` and having some delay.

My `Controller_OnPlayerChangedState`:

```
private void Controller_OnPlayerChangedState(object sender, MultiPlayerController.OnChangeStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState == AudioPlayer_State.Playing)
    {
        Duration = AudioPanel.Controller.GetDuration();
        panel.SetCurrentPositionAsync((long)Duration);
    }
    else if(e.NewState != AudioPlayer_State.Playing && e.NewState != AudioPlayer_State.Paused)
        panel.SetCurrentPositionAsync(0);
}
```

Works fine but I don't know if I can have another solution.

Comment: Can we see the code where `changing` is called or triggered. Basically it seems vulnerable for concurrent operations. You could consider a `lock` but that would be a dirty trick.

Comment: I edited the post with the function where changing it's called. Duration it's a property with OnPropertyChagned being called and consequently changing too.

Comment: Okay, this can be a though nut to crack.... You have some options, but the most preferable would be to not use `obj.Animation = new ...`. The reason: it might collide during concurrent calls. Is there a way to just reset, and not `new` the animation?

Comment: Well, I don't see how to reuse the DoubleAnimation object. The biggest problem I think is if the older value is equal  the same. The change it's just ignored (with some reason) but I don't want this behavior. Consequently changing callback it's not called so I can't reuse the DoubleAnimation object

Comment: I posted a solution, but I don't know if it's a good. I will let this thread a little longer open so someone can try to help with any ideia.

Comment: Ah, nice; let us know if it worked.

Comment: Works ... well... but I prefer to find a more beauty solution if exists (probably yes).